# Upload Image Width and Height get in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to React and react hook I want to upload an image from anywhere but I want to know the width and height of a select image before storing it in the database. I want to store the original image metadata width and height. anyone can help me

Comment: check this https://davidwalsh.name/get-image-dimensions if it helps. Also just search google there are already many posts in stackoverflow itself regarding this.

Comment: In React hook it's not working i tried

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to use FileReader, something like this should work:

```
const image = new Image();
let fr = new FileReader();

    fr.onload = function() {
      if (fr !== null && typeof fr.result == "string") {
        image.src = fr.result;
      }
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(inputFile);


    image.onload = async function() {
     const width = image.width;
    };
```

You can take a look here: https://github.com/toncic/Image-Classification/blob/master/src/Components/ImageClassification.tsx#L45

Comment: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'FileList'.  TS2339

    147 |     if (!isNull(event.target.files)) {
    148 |       let imageList = event.target.files;
  > 149 |       imageList.forEach(element => {
        |                 ^
    150 |         let img = new Image()
    151 |         img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(element)
    152 |         img.onload = () => { console.log(img.width); }

I am getting this error while running code in react typescript

Comment: @HariharaManikandan can you create some code example, it will be much easier to find a problem?